# PHP, MySQL - find a specific part in the field and delete it

Tags: php, mysql

For example:
In my table I have text field with following text:

**The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.**

How can I find **brown fox** and delete it, so that new field value is:

**The quick jumped over the lazy dog.**

Is this possible to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update `table`
    set `field` = replace(`field`, 'brown fox ', '')
    where `field` = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.';
```

**EDIT:** As @Cranio pointed out, we need to remove spacing on either side of 'brown fox' in order to get the anticipated result.

Comment: This is the simplest, easiest, and most recommended solution. +1

Comment: As a side note for @Sasha, remember that in this case the result is "The quick jumped..." with TWO spaces between "quick" and "jumped". Not sure if he wants correct spacing too. (My solution has the same problem)

Comment: I guess that the extra spacing can be done by adding one in the string I want to delete. Thanks for the side note.

Comment: Yes, it is the most obvious solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    LEFT("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
        INSTR("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog","brown fox")-1),
    MID("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
        INSTR("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog","brown fox")+
        LENGTH("brown fox"))
)
```

Using fields it would be

```
SELECT
CONCAT(
    LEFT(myField,
        INSTR(myField,substring)-1),
    MID(myField,
        INSTR(myField)+
        LENGTH(substring))
)
```

Comment: Just noting that this will only replace the -first- occurrence of 'brown fox'.  My solution replaces all occurrence of the search string.

Comment: You are absolutely right, by the way I just don't realize how I didn't think of replace in first instance (as I know that function very well and used it a lot).

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve the field using `like` edit it, then save it back.

Comment: Although possible, it's quite slow and adds extra overhead by using additional queries and is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Answer should specify HOW to edit it, and inside MySQL, not outside.